# cannot open table after copying database

Tags: mysql

i copied the database folder from my old backups to the new MySQL install today. I can see that the database is available after I restarted my MySQL but I cannot connect to any of the tables.
I get the following error. I checked the link but cannot get any ideas to fix my issue. is there any step that I missed after I copied the database folder?

```
> 2016-08-23T21:31:06.754512Z 10 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table dbtorontotrader/rawdatas from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2016-08-23T21:31:26.125763Z 8 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table dbtorontotrader/amibrokerscans from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
```

Update: i only have the data files from my old db which was mysql5.5 and I am copying them into the new MySQL db which is MySQL 5.7
I ran the mysqlcheck and I can see errors. how can I fix them?

```
    C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --all-databases
I got the following. how can I fix it?
enter code here

dbtorontotrader.amibrokerscans
Error    : Table 'dbtorontotrader.amibrokerscans' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
dbtorontotrader.backtest
Error    : Table 'dbtorontotrader.backtest' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
dbtorontotrader.customqueries
Error    : Table 'dbtorontotrader.customqueries' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
dbtorontotrader.davealerts
Error    : Table 'dbtorontotrader.davealerts' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
dbtorontotrader.davetrades
Error    : Table 'dbtorontotrader.davetrades' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
dbtorontotrader.executions
Error    : Table 'dbtorontotrader.executions' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
dbtorontotrader.ib
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `ib`" or dump/reload to fix it!
dbtorontotrader.mb
error    : Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `mb`" or dump/reload to fix it!
dbtorontotrader.mlsstats
Error    : Table 'dbtorontotrader.mlsstats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
```

Comment: it's probably better to do a mysqldump of your old dbs and then rebuild them in the new server. Is that still an option?

Comment: You can CHECK TABLE to see if there is any problem or if the table is corrupt. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html

Comment: It seems it got corrupt after recovering it from the backup.

Comment: just added more diagnostics info. how can I fix it?

Comment: You can try a repair program for that, just search google for one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the sqldumps and rebuilt the database